# mouseUp on an empty row in the Data Grid with native mobile scroller is causing an error

Tags: livecode

I'm using a native scroller for a Data Grid displaying about 700 records. When the number of visible records is small (1-2) and they do not cover the whole height of the Data Grid rectangle then when executing mouseUp on an empty row in the Data Grid I'm getting this error:

executing at 2:57:26 PM

Type    Chunk: can't find background

Object: main

Line:   send mouseUp to field "Label" of group "Row Template 0003" of group "dgList" of group "dgListMask" of group "DataGrid 1" of card "main"

Hint:   mouseUp

The line above is a part of the scroller script in the card script enabling simple tapping on the row when not scrolling the DG:

```
on mouseUp
   if not isScrolling then
      send mouseUp to field "Label" of group "Row Template 0003" of group "dgList" of group "dgListMask" of group "DataGrid 1" of card "main"
   end if
end mouseUp
```

To fix the error I changed it to:

```
on mouseUp
   if gCurrentIndex = empty then -- added this line in the hope that it will fix it but it does not
      exit to top -- added this line in the hope that it will fix it but it does not
   else -- added this line in the hope that it will fix it but it does not
      if not isScrolling then
         send mouseUp to field "Label" of group "Row Template 0003" of group "dgList" of group "dgListMask" of group "DataGrid 1" of card "main"
      end if
   end if
end mouseUp
```

but it did not solve he problem.

The code in the Row Template Label is:

```
global gCurrentView,gCurrentLine,gCurrentIndex

on mouseUp
   put the text of me into fld "foneline" of cd "oneline"
   put the dgText of grp "DataGrid 1" into gCurrentView
   put the dgHilitedLines of grp "DataGrid 1" into gCurrentLine
   put the dgHilitedIndexes of grp "DataGrid 1" into gCurrentIndex
   lock screen for visual effect
   unlock screen with visual effect reveal right slow
   go cd "oneline"
end mouseUp
```

To replicate the error follow these steps:

1. open the stack
2. click on "My Selection" button
3. click on OK on the message "Sorry..."
4. click on the grey star below the quote (select just 1 quote)
5. click on "Dashboard" button
6. click on "My Selection" button
7. click on the light yellow area below the quote
8. the Error window will show up

if this first time the error does not show then continue

1. click on the text quoete above the the light yellow area
2. click on the "Entire selection" button
3. click on the light yellow area below the quote - this time error will come up for sure.

The above steps may look complex but it's very simple once you see the stack which is here: [DG-empty row error.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/disxkn4jc5hofca/DG-empty%20row%20error.zip)

How to fix this error?

Comment: You shouldn't be hard coding any names to groups used for rows in a data grid. The names are dynamic and may or may not exist. So don't target group "Row Template 0003" of group "dgList" with your send. I'm not sure why you need this line anyway, does the native scroller not pass mouse events through? Wouldn't the row controls just get the mouseUp message if you passed it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if gCurrentIndex has been declared as a global in the second block of code ...

```
global gCurrentIndex
on mouseUp
   if gCurrentIndex = empty then -- added this line in the hope that it will fix it but it does not
      exit to top -- added this line in the hope that it will fix it but it does not
   else -- added this line in the hope that it will fix it but it does not
      if not isScrolling then
         send mouseUp to field "Label" of group "Row Template 0003" of group "dgList" of group "dgListMask" of group "DataGrid 1" of card "main"
      end if
   end if
end mouseUp
```

Comment: Yes, globals are declared properly (see the stack), I just did not include that line in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding this block of code to the text field of the Row Template of the DG instead of to the scroller code:

```
  if gCurrentIndex = empty then
     exit to top
  else
     lock screen for visual effect
     unlock screen with visual effect reveal right slow 
     go cd "oneline"
  end if
```

Re this line:

```
send mouseUp to field "Label" of group "Row Template 0003" of group "dgList" of group "dgListMask" of group "DataGrid 1" of card "main"
```

and its alternative:

```
send mouseUp to field "Label"
```

I tested the scrolling and tapping on the row with and without this line and there is no difference, it works. I don't remember where from I got that line, probably from someone on the LC Forum. The idea was to make sure that when touching the row to scroll the DG it does not go to the card "oneline". I'll keep watching how it works now.